# Update Profile model that extends default User with middleware (last_activity field) DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I'm trying to update Profile model, which extends the default User model. But something clearly off because Profile displays no entries. Could you please suggest how to properly update model in middleware that extends another one?

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField()  # filled in by middleware

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

**view.py**

```
class ProfileList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

**middleware.py**

```
from django.utils import timezone

class UpdateLastActivityMiddleware(object):
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    return self.get_response(request)

def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # Update last visit time after request finished processing.
        # I'm trying to create record - in case user had no activity before
        Profile.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.pk).update_or_create(last_activity=timezone.now())  # <-- looks like something is off here, since I'm not sure how to correctly update extended model
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'core.middleware.UpdateLastActivityMiddleware',
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Profile.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.pk).update_or_create(last_activity=timezone.now())
```

with

```
user.profile.last_activity=timezone.now()
user.save()
```

Reason being that since it's a one to one relationship you do not need `update_or_create`, since a user will always have a profile and the reverse relation should work out of the box and you'd be able to just update the property `last_activity` directly.

Comment: Thank you - could you please suggest what should be ```user``` in this case? I've tried several options but none of them worked, getting different errors.

Comment: @venv could you try `user = request.user` ? or try prepending the `request.` in front of the code in my response?

Comment: yes, I've tried it, but I'm getting ```RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /api/posts/
User has no profile.``` Looks like because the Profile is empty and has no records. Not sure why OneToOneField relation doesn't help here, will investigate more.

Comment: @venv use `post_save` to fire up creation of a user profile. This helps you with the automatic creation of the profile object once you create a new user in your system.

Comment: thank you so much! I've added a signal to populate Profiles on User creation and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've ended up with thanks to @Borko Kovacev and a lot of googling:

**middleware.py**

```
class UpdateLastActivityMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')

        # need to separately detect user when used middleware with JWT (else Anonymous User)
        try:
            auth_res = authentication.JWTAuthentication().authenticate(request)
        except InvalidToken:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid token'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        if auth_res:
            request.user = auth_res[0]
        
        # save last_activity on each authenticated request
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            request.user.profile.last_activity = timezone.now()  # assigning last_activity
            request.user.save()  # this triggers signal on User model saving
            print(f'MIDDLEWARE saved last_activity for {request.user}')
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)  # to populate Profile on user creation (else fails because Profile record does not exist for user)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print('signals create_profile ')
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)  # to update Profile on user update (triggered by middleware)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('signals save_profile ')
    instance.profile.save()
```